# Error while parsing RSS feeds

Tags: java, android, rss

I keep getting the same error every time. I have been working on it for about 4 hours now.
It is for a RSS feed.

The error is probably simple but I am a beginner, so please, bear with me.

I tried to add `StringBuffer` which is where I started getting an error. If I remove the `StringBuffer` then the app continues to work but I would prefer using it.

The [original code is from here](http://www.itcuties.com/android/how-to-write-android-rss-parser/).

### My code

#### Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // A reference to the local object
    private MainActivity local;

     /**
    * This method creates main application view
    */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         // Set view
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         // Set reference to this activity
         local = this;

         GetRSSDataTask task = new GetRSSDataTask();

         // Start download RSS task
         task.execute("http://cantstophiphop.com/feed/");

         // Debug the thread name
         Log.d("RssReader", Thread.currentThread().getName());
     }

     private class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem> > {

         @Override
         protected List<RssItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {

             // Debug the task thread name
             Log.d("RssReader", Thread.currentThread().getName());

             try {
                 // Create RSS reader
                 RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(urls[0]);

                 // Parse RSS, get items

             } catch (Exception e) {
                 Log.e(" RssReader", e.getMessage());
             }

             return null;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {

             // Get a ListView from main view
             ListView itcItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

             // Create a list adapter
             ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>  (local,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
             // Set list adapter for the ListView
             itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);

             // Set list view item click listener
             itcItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));
         }
     }  
}
```

#### RssParseHandler.java

```
public class RssParseHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    // List of items parsed
    private List<RssItem> rssItems;
    // We have a local reference to an object which is constructed while parser is working on an item tag
    // Used to reference item while parsing
    private RssItem currentItem;
    // We have two indicators which are used to differentiate whether a tag title or link is being processed by the parser
    // Parsing title indicator
    private boolean parsingTitle;
    // Parsing link indicator
    private boolean parsingLink;
    //private rssTitle;
    private StringBuffer rssTitle;

    public RssParseHandler() {
        rssItems = new ArrayList();

    }

    // We have an access method which returns a list of items that are read from the RSS feed. This method will be called when parsing is done.
    public List<RssItem> getItems() {
        return rssItems;
    }

     // The StartElement method creates an empty RssItem object when an item start tag is being processed. When a title or link tag are being processed appropriate indicators are set to true.
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes  attributes) throws SAXException {

        if ("item".equals(qName)) {
            currentItem = new RssItem();
        } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
            parsingTitle = true;
            rssTitle = new StringBuffer(); //Add this line *****************************
        } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
            parsingLink = true;
        }
    }

    // The EndElement method adds the  current RssItem to the list when a closing item tag is processed. It sets appropriate indicators to false -  when title and link closing tags are processed
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException{

        if ("item".equals(qName)) {
            rssItems.add(currentItem);
            currentItem = null;
        } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
            parsingTitle = false;
            currentItem.setTitle(rssTitle.toString()); //Add this line *****************
        } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
            parsingLink = false;
        }
     }

    // Characters method fills current RssItem object with data when title and link tag content is being processed
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

        if (parsingTitle) {
            if (currentItem != null)
                rssTitle.append(new String(ch, start, length)); //add This line ***************
            } else if (parsingLink) {
                if (currentItem != null) { 
                currentItem.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
                parsingLink = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### LOGcat

```
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573):    at      android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:480)
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573):    at com.dailyloudrss.MainActivity$GetRSSDataTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:78)
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573):    at com.dailyloudrss.MainActivity$GetRSSDataTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-30 19:03:20.792: E/AndroidRuntime(13573):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the actual error? Is it a compile error or does it crash?

Comment: Hi, its a crash also ive added logcat. apologies... Many thanks

Comment: doInBackground appears to always return null. That is passed to onPostExecute into 'result' which is then used as the data for the adapter, hence the NPE when the listview attempts to render. Do you not need something like 'return rssReader.getItems();' where you have the comment // Parse RSS, get items ?

Comment: Hi, i tired to add that in and got many errors so it didn't compile. is there anything else i could try